# Website com conteúdo centralizado porém fora de conjunto com o background

Tags: html, css, html5

Estou com meu website pronto, porém, queria mudar algo que vem me incomodando faz tempo.

Estou com certa dificuldade em deixar o site dividido em duas camadas, tentarei exemplificar para ficar mais fácil.

O layout do Facebook possui a parte central onde aparece o feed, e o background.

O feed é uma div (?) centralizada.
Qual linha de código me facilitaria a chegar neste resultado?

Edit.: Outro exemplo é o site do LinkedIn, onde o conteúdo é centralizado e desconexo do background do site.

Link do site, caso seja de ajuda:

> https://esteticaflordeiris.com

Comment: Não entendi a colocação do Facebook. Nem background tem a não ser uma cor sólida.

Comment: Não é sobre cor.
Print do facebook: http://prntscr.com/lhfdoa 
Print do LinkedIn: http://prntscr.com/lhfe68

Pode-se perceber que o conteúdo a frente é desconexo do fundo.
Ou seja, o fundo permanece fixo enquanto apenas essa div a frente se mexe, entende?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Não sei se e isto que queres corrigir mas se quiseres alinhar tudo primeiro deves alinhar a foto com este css (mudei a width)

```css
#showcase img {
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: 60px;
}
```

Depois o texto com este css (se quixeres podes por 0 fica melhor na margin)

```css
.h1, .h2, .h3, h1, h2, h3 {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

a seguir usei este codigo na section 2

```html
<section id="info2" style="padding-left: 0px;margin-left: 500px;">
```

por ultimo nesta secção dei este codigo

```html
<section id="contact" style="/*! text-align: center; */padding-left: 750px;">
```

nao sei se e isto que queres mas também nao percebo muito bem a pergunta

Comment: isto é para alinhares tudo ao centro mas como disse não sei se e isto que queres.  Se queres incorporar feed do facebook ou outro site tenta procurar por iframe pois como sao codigo ja arranjados por eles pode-te facilitar a vida por norma no site deles esta como (input ou embed com icone "< >")

Comment: É quase lá, fazendo isso fica tudo no centro, tudo bem, é algo que eu queria.
Porém, eu queria que ficasse neste estilo aqui: http://prntscr.com/lhfdoa e http://prntscr.com/lhfe68

Comment: pois isso são containers experimenta usar bootstap e tens templates já feitos mas procura aqui https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/overview/

Answer (score -2):

Aí cara, um exemplo de uso, deixando a `<div>` "desconectada" do conteúdo e permitindo que ele possa se mover, sem preocupação com o que está do lado, por exemplo:

```css
#menu-vertical{
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: white;
}
#principal{
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 350px;
  height: 1200px;
  background-color: white;
}
body{
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="menu-vertical">
     <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
       <tr><td>Item 1</td></tr>
       <tr><td>Item 2</td></tr>
       <tr><td>Item 3</td></tr>
       <tr><td>Item 4</td></tr>
     </table>
  </div>

  <div id="principal">
     <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
       <tr><td>Item 1</td></tr>
       <tr><td>Item 2</td></tr>
       <tr><td>Item 3</td></tr>
       <tr><td>Item 4</td></tr>
     </table>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Exatamente isto, obrigado!
Agora irei fazer os ajustes juntamente com o amigo joao dias que me deu uma ajuda também!

Comment: @LucasMarra boa, se alguma resposta atendeu mais suas necessidades, marque-a como a aceita ;)

Answer (score -2):

Se o seu objetivo for centralizar uma div é só adicionar no CSS a propriedade "margin" com o valor "auto", desta forma: 
`margin: auto;`

Caso o objetivo seja fixar o conteúdo em uma posição especifica de tal forma que mesmo movendo o scroll ele nunca saia do ponto desejado, então no CSS você pode fazer algo assim:

`position: fixed;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 tansform: translate(-50%, -50%);`